# Overriding of the template for the Attachment “thumbnails” in the Media Grid isn't working

Tags: media, media-library, thumbnails, get-template-part

I'm trying to customize the template of the Media Browser (when clicking on "Add Media" button within Edit Post page), by adding a caption with the filename on each thumbnail so I don't need to select the image to check its filename on the Attachment Details panel.

What I have done so far is a version of the solution described in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948448/8717608

I'm using the "tmpl-attachment" template, from line 506 of media-template.php which is exactly what I need to customize:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/media-template.php

By clicking the Add Media button I was expecting to see all the thumbs with its filename in a black background on the bottom of the image, but nothing is happening.
Looks like I'm missing something and I would appreciate any help to find out what is wrong.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', 'add_media_overrides' );
function add_media_overrides() {
    add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'override_media_templates' );
}
function override_media_templates(){
    ?> 
    <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-attachment_custom">
        <div class="attachment-preview js--select-attachment type-{{ data.type }} subtype-{{ data.subtype }} {{ data.orientation }}">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <# if ( data.uploading ) { #>
                    <div class="media-progress-bar"><div style="width: {{ data.percent }}%"></div></div>
                <# } else if ( 'image' === data.type && data.sizes ) { #>
                    <div class="centered">
                        <img src="{{ data.size.url }}" draggable="false" alt=""  style="height: 90%; transform: translate(-50%,-55%);"/>
                        <div style="
                            transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
                            background-color: black;
                            color: white;
                            margin-top: 50%;
                            font-size: 80%;
                            z-index: 9999;
                            position: relative;
                            vertical-align: middle;
                        ">{{ data.filename }}</div>
                    </div>
                <# } else { #>
                    <div class="centered">
                        <# if ( data.image && data.image.src && data.image.src !== data.icon ) { #>
                            <img src="{{ data.image.src }}" class="thumbnail" draggable="false" alt="" />
                        <# } else if ( data.sizes && data.sizes.medium ) { #>
                            <img src="{{ data.sizes.medium.url }}" class="thumbnail" draggable="false" alt="" />
                        <# } else { #>
                            <img src="{{ data.icon }}" class="icon" draggable="false" alt="" />
                        <# } #>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filename">
                        <div>{{ data.filename }}</div>
                    </div>
                <# } #>
            </div>
            <# if ( data.buttons.close ) { #>
                <button type="button" class="button-link attachment-close media-modal-icon"><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Remove' ); ?></span></button>
            <# } #>
        </div>
        <# if ( data.buttons.check ) { #>
            <button type="button" class="check" tabindex="-1"><span class="media-modal-icon"></span><span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Deselect' ); ?></span></button>
        <# } #>
        <#
        var maybeReadOnly = data.can.save || data.allowLocalEdits ? '' : 'readonly';
        if ( data.describe ) {
            if ( 'image' === data.type ) { #>
                <input type="text" value="{{ data.caption }}" class="describe" data-setting="caption"
                    placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Caption this image&hellip;' ); ?>" {{ maybeReadOnly }} />
            <# } else { #>
                <input type="text" value="{{ data.title }}" class="describe" data-setting="title"
                    <# if ( 'video' === data.type ) { #>
                        placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Describe this video&hellip;' ); ?>"
                    <# } else if ( 'audio' === data.type ) { #>
                        placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Describe this audio file&hellip;' ); ?>"
                    <# } else { #>
                        placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Describe this media file&hellip;' ); ?>"
                    <# } #> {{ maybeReadOnly }} />
            <# }
        } #>
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            if( typeof wp.media.view.Attachment != 'undefined' ){
                wp.media.view.Attachment.prototype.template = wp.media.template( 'attachment-custom' );
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo, and instead of:

```
wp.media.view.Attachment.prototype.template = wp.media.template( 'attachment-custom' );
```

Should be:

```
wp.media.view.Attachment.prototype.template = wp.media.template( 'attachment_custom' );
```